# unable to start sql 2005 on windows 2003 two node cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-agent

SQL server Agent is not starting......

In the SQLAGENT log i found this error.......

2009-10-24 22:49:36 - ? [393] Waiting for SQL Server to recover databases...

2009-10-24 22:49:40 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 5845, Address Windowing Extensions (AWE) requires the 'lock pages in memory' privilege which is not currently present in the access token of the process. [SQLSTATE 42000] (DisableAgentXPs)

2009-10-24 22:49:40 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 15281, SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'dbo.sp_sqlagent_has_server_access' of component 'Agent XPs' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Agent XPs' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Agent XPs', see "Surface Area Configuration" in SQL Server Books Online. [SQLSTATE 42000] (ConnIsLoginSysAdmin)

2009-10-24 22:49:41 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 15281, SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'dbo.sp_sqlagent_get_startup_info' of component 'Agent XPs' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Agent XPs' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Agent XPs', see "Surface Area Configuration" in SQL Server Books Online. [SQLSTATE 42000]

2009-10-24 22:49:41 - ? [100] Microsoft SQLServerAgent version 9.00.4035.00 (x86 unicode retail build) : Process ID 4144

2009-10-24 22:49:41 - ? [101] SQL Server version 9.00.4035 (0 connection limit)

2009-10-24 22:49:41 - ? [102] SQL Server ODBC driver version 9.00.4035

2009-10-24 22:49:41 - ? [103] NetLib being used by driver is DBNETLIB.DLL; Local host server is

2009-10-24 22:49:41 - ? [310] 8 processor(s) and 4096 MB RAM detected

2009-10-24 22:49:41 - ? [339] Local computer is PROD-SQL05-OLTP running Windows NT 5.2 (3790) Service Pack 2

2009-10-24 22:49:41 - ! [000] SQLServerAgent must be able to connect to SQLServer as SysAdmin, but '(Unknown)' is not a member of the SysAdmin role

2009-10-24 22:49:41 - ? [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normally)

please anyone tell me the prblm..........

Iam getting this error when doing sql server failover to other node in a two node cluster(MSCS)...

Answer (score 0):

Your security is messed up somewhere, or SQL agent is running under the wrong account

```
2009-10-24 22:49:41 - ! [000] SQLServerAgent must be able to connect to SQLServer as SysAdmin, but '(Unknown)' is not a member of the SysAdmin role
```